# What does $φ(a) = a$ mean in this statement?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, ring-isomorphism

Let $F$ be a field and let $φ:F[x] \to F[x]$ be an isomorphism such that $φ(a)=a $ for every $a$ in $F$. Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $φ(f(x))$ is. [Hint: First prove that for any $g(x)$ in $F[x]$, $g(x)$ is nonconstant if and only if $φ(g(x))$ is nonconstant.]

I found the solution online and everywhere I find it, its basically translating this question to:

Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x+1)$ is. I dont understand how this problem translates to this.

When I tried proving this I thought the transformation meant $φ(f(x))= f(x)$.

So I guess the question Im asking is what does φ(a) = a mean in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F[x]$ is just the ring of polynomials with coefficients from the field $F$. So if $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a \in F$, it is just saying that all the constants in $F[x]$ get mapped to themselves under the mapping $\phi$ i.e. polynomials of the form $f(x)=a$ for $a \in F$ get mapped to themselves.

To prove the statement, first suppose that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. Then suppose $\phi(f(x)) = g(x)h(x)$ for some $g(x),h(x) \in F[x]$. Now,

$$\phi(f(x)) = g(x)h(x) \implies f(x)= \phi^{-1}(g(x)h(x)) = \phi^{-1}(g(x))\phi^{-1}(h(x))$$

But $f(x)$ is irreducible so either $\phi^{-1}(g(x))=a$ or $\phi^{-1}(h(x))=a$ for some $a \in F[x]$ and hence either $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit so $f(x)$ is irreducible.

For the other direction, suppose $\phi(f(x))$ is irreducible. Then if $f(x)$ were reducible, we could write $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for some non-constant polynomials in $g(x),h(x) \in F[x]$. But then we would have $$\phi(f(x))=\phi(g(x)h(x))= \phi(g(x)) \phi(h(x))$$

Using the hint you are given, $\phi(g(x))$ and $\phi(h(x))$ are non-constant since $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are assumed to be non-constant and hence $\phi(f(x))$ is reducible which is a contradiction. Thus $f(x)$ must be irreducible.

Comment: So when you say polynomials of the form f(x)=a, are we referring to nonzero constant polynomials?

Comment: Is that fact ever used in the proof?

Comment: For your first comment, the polynomials can be zero since $0 \in F$. The fact that $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a \in F$ is just saying that every element in $F$ that is also in $F[x]$ is sent to itself by the map.

Comment: For your second comment, we used the fact that $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a \in F$ in the first half of the proof. We came to the conclusion that either $\phi^{-1}(g(x))=a$ or $\phi^{-1}(h(x))=a$. If you apply $\phi$ to both sides of these equations you have $\phi(a)=g(x)$ or $\phi(a)=h(x)$. Then you use the assumption so that $g(x)=a$ or $h(x)=a$ which implies one of the functions has to be a unit so that $f$ is ireeducible.